# Is it possible to capture application screen buffers in linux?

Tags: linux, vnc

i am creating an application similar to VNC.
VNC captures screen frames and send it to the remote machine. 
frames are captured and displayed on the remote machine.

In my project i want to send application frames to the remote machine.
eg.
if i start video player on linux machine,video will be started here but the 
video frames will be sent to the remote machine and will be displayed there.

i referred to this link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292535/linux-screen-desktop-video-capture-over-network-and-vnc-framerate)

Comment: You need to first familiarize yourself with the X-Windows client/server model.

Comment: in my case remote machine will be an android device..will this architecture work for linux(server)--->android(client)??

Comment: Have a look at `import(1)` which can capture the contents of a displayed window.  But I fear whatever you are trying to achieve will run into the problem that frame capturing and sending it over the network to display it somewhere else will not be fast enough for videos.  Expect no more than three frames per second by that architecture.  You can have a look at TeamViewer (a commercial product) which is something like VNC and which also is available for Android.  I managed to remote control my Linux box from my phone using this.  But I think this also is nothing for video streaming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this http://my20percent.wordpress.com/2012/02/27/android-x-server/  link
answers my question

i am able to run linux apps on android. :)